# Ember auth transition.retry() after login doesn't transit while testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I am having some issues with testing my login and related features of my app. The app works perfectly, but the test fails. For testing, I use a `Qunit` with `karma`

I have created few authenticated routes(say accounts) which one can only visit after logging in. If a user goes to accounts route without logging, he is redirected to login page and after successful login, redirected back to the accounts page.

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.redirectToLogin(transition);
    }
  },
  redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
    var loginController;
    loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
    loginController.set("attemptedTransition", transition);
    this.transitionTo("login");
  },
  events: {
    error: function(reason, transition) {
      this.redirectToLogin(transition);
    }
  }
});


App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  attemptedTransition: null,
  loginUser: function() {
    var attemptedTran, form_data, router, that;
    router = this.get("target");
    form_data = this.getProperties("email", "password");
    attemptedTran = this.get('attemptedTransition');
    that = this;
    return $.post("/sessions", {
      'session': form_data
    }, (function(results) {
      return Ember.run(function() {
        App.AuthManager.authenticate(results.api_key.access_token, results.api_key.user_id);
        if (attemptedTran) {
          attemptedTran.retry();
          return that.set('attemptedTransition', null);
        } else {
          return router.transitionTo("index");
        }
      });
    }), "json");
  }
});

App.AccountsRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('account');
  }
});
```

I am trying to test this using

```
test("account index", function() {
    expect(3); // Ensure that we will perform one assertion

  visit("/accounts").andThen(function() {
    equal(currentRouteName(),"login",'Accounts is an authenticated Route. so redirected to login page');
    fillIn('input[type=text]', "j@j.com");
    fillIn('input[type=password]', "jjjjjj");
    click("button:submit").andThen(function(){
      equal(currentRouteName(),"accounts",'After login redirected back to account page.');
    })
 });
```

But this test fails after logging in and doesn't redirect back to the accounts page.
Any help??

Comment: If you run the test alone, does it end up redirecting, but the test fails, because I could see where Ember wouldn't be aware of the $.post starting/finishing and would assume it was done clicking the button move on to your `equal` assertion.

Comment: After clicking on submit button, the user gets logged in successfully as the menu on navbar changes accordingly from "login" to "logout" and  other authenticated routes shows up as well but it doesn't redirect at all. Its not that test fails to capture redirection, but its not redirecting at all when running test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're setting `previousTransition` then getting `attemptedTransition`.  `attemptedTransition` should always be null according to the logic above.

Comment: That was a mistake, I had copied that part from [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/#toc_storing-and-retrying-a-transition). I have updated the code now as it is.